# img наложить на border

Tags: slick.js, img, border

Всем привет! У меня есть слайдер подключенный через slick, дизайнеры хотят, чтобы при перелистывании слайдера у меня листалась и дата с точкой (а она наложена на border-bottom), в слайдере по умолчанию задано overflow: hidden; , что не дает мне с помощью position: absolute закинуть картинку (ту самую точку) на мой border-bottom (потому что она обрезается). Пыталась задать border с помощью after, но не видит border совсем. Во вложение закину что хочет дизайнер и что у меня выходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.slider_wrap {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.slider_box {
  max-width: 890px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_wrap">
    <div class="slider_box">
        <div>
            <img class="slider_img" src="img/work.png" alt="">
            <div class="slider_data">17.03.23</div>
            <img class="dots" src="img/dots.svg" alt="dots">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не видя кода точно не скажу, но знаю, что нужно задать элементу, который отвечает за overflow: hidden; - задать нижний padding-bottom;. Правда если border задан именно этому элементу, он отодвинется вместе с ним, но зато как вы и писали возможно получится с помощью after. В общем отступ padding-bottom обязателен, а дальше уже надо смотреть.

Comment: .slick-list {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    */padding-bottom: 20px;/*
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

Вот такой код прописан от слайдера slick, добавила падинг ему, но он зачеркивает его и не хочет считывать

Comment: у вас padding: 0; прописан, может поэтому? Вы задали padding-bottom: 20px;, а потом у вас идёт padding: 0;

Comment: Можете написать padding: 0 0 20px;

Comment: Точно даже не заметила.. Исправила, как теперь получается: border отодвигается от нашего блока и точка становится выше, когда задаю точке боттом еще ниже (bottom: -25px; - а было bottom: -5px;), она все равно обрезается нашим блоком

Comment: так вы не отпускайте точки, точки должны находиться в зоне padding-а, дайте им bottom: 0;. Потом выводите нижнюю линию не через border, а через :after, даёте ему position: absolute; bottom: сколько-то, что бы точки пересекало посередине, задаёте z-index точкам больше, чем линии, если точки кликабельные. Надеюсь сможете after-у сделать псевдо border в 1px))

Comment: .slick-list:after {content: ''; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 4px; display: block; width: 100%; height: 1px; background-color: white;} -примерно так

Comment: все получилось!! спасибо вам огромное!!